# Talend get current filename

Tags: filenames, talend

I want to load excel files into the mysql database and check that they do not already exist, my problem is that I can not extract the name of the current file.

For example, I have the following files `A.xlsx`,  `B.xlsx` and `C.xls`.

It return always  `B.xlsx`

[image]

Comment: Welcome @huda_tt. Can you try to give a bit more detail about what is happening? Could you include examples? When you say "it always returns" can you say what "it" is? Where are you trying to get the filename from? In which component?

Comment: hi @Screwtape  I want to extract the current filename first in the "tdatabaseinput" to make the query {"SELECT
   `processedfile`.`NOM`
FROM `processedfile` WHERE NAME = '" + ((String) globalMap.get ("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")) + "'"
}

if it does not already exist I want to insert it (current file name) in the mysqltable "prossedfile"  using "tfixedflowinput"  but the value inserted is always the same ~$B.xlsx

Comment: The link between tFileLink_1 and tFixedFlowInput_1 is not iterating - it will only pick up the (first/last?) iteration. Try running your subjob from a "run if" from the "disponibilite_3g" component, or even the map component.

Comment: ok @Screwtape  i try to do this job to extract current filename  and identifie the probleme
[enter image description here][1]


but i still have the name of latest file
[enter image description here][2] 


[enter image description here][3]


[enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFjk3.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia6RW.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi3bW.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETqOu.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that your "RunIf" link is before the iterator, and therefore it's not being triggered at the right time.

The image below shows a simplified version, where I list the rows in the spreadsheets and then the file names. If I connected the second subjob to the `tFileList_1` component, as you did in the question, I only get the logs from `tLogRow_1` and the last filename by `tLogRow_2`.

[image: Talend Job Example]

With the link as shown, behind the iterator, then I get spreadsheet contents listed and then the title of it:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
A|B|C
D|E|F
A.xlsx
Col1|Col2|Col3
A|B|C
D|E|F
B.xlsx
Col1|Col2|Col3
A|B|C
D|E|F
C.xlsx
```

I am assuming that you have filted out the duplicated files in the `tMap` component, so if you link your second subjob from the `disponsibilite_3d` component, I think you will get the result you are looking for.

Comment: thank you @Screwtape but witch i want is to get only the name of file used in the job (disponibilite_3G in this case ) to save it into a table mysql and not names of  all directory files any help please

Comment: Does your tMap filter the files that aren’t used, so that it only gets to the database update when the file hasn’t already been used?

Comment: yes that's which i want , this filter in the tfilelist i don't know how i can do it , sorry but i am beginner in talend

Comment: I try to select the file names of the DB table with tmysqlinput and then compare the value with the current file name to check if it does not exist already does not exist already