# fcurrent file name talend

Tags: filenames, talend

I need to extract the name of currentfile in tLogRow  to use it in a MySql request
but instead of currentfilename ,i get the name off latest file in the directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383836/talend-get-current-filename/53393988. I have updated my answer in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, the connector between the tFileList and tFileProperties should be an iterate rather than OnSubjobOk.

Hope this helps.